# How to delete entries from Vuex store using dynamic path as payload for a mutation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

I want to create a mutation for the vuex state, but making it dynamically update the state - to have the payload include a path to the object I want to delete the element from and the key.

1. Dispatching the action

```
deleteOption(path, key) 
{ this.$store.dispatch('deleteOptionAction', {path, key}) }
```

2. Commiting the mutation

```
deleteOptionAction ({ commit }, payload) { commit('deleteOption', payload) }
```

3. The mutation receives the payload with path = 'state.xmlValues.Offers[0].data.Pars' and key = 0

```
deleteOption (state, payload) { 
  let stt = eval('state.' + payload.path)
  Vue.delete(stt, payload.key)
  // delete stt[payload.key] - works the same as Vue.delete
  state.xmlValues.Offers[0].data.Pars = Object.assign({}, Object.values(stt))
   }
```

I have tried to use the state[payload.path] syntax - but this does not work. 
The path includes the string 'state.xmlValues.Offers[0].data.Pars', so to make it work, I have used let stt = eval('state.' + payload.path).
But then, to delete an element from the state becomes tricky:
when using Vue.delete(stt, payload.key) - it will only delete the element's key locally stored in stt variable, not in the state.

Then I re-assigned the state objects with the stt (from which the needed element is deleted already), hardcoding the path - and that's what I try to avoid:

```
state.xmlValues.Offers[0].data.Pars = Object.assign({}, Object.values(stt))
```

**How do I pass a path to the store, then use it to delete an object in the state without hardcoding the path explicitly?**

As for my other mutation addOption, I also used the dynamic path to the state object  - and it works great when using the dynamic path evaluated in stt

```
addOption (state, payload) {
      let stt = eval('state.' + payload.path)
      Vue.set(stt, payload.key, payload.newEl)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: Don't use `eval(..)`. Ever. This function allows for arbitrary code execution, and you do **nothing** to sanitise the value!

A more sane option would be to parse your path yourself. You could write something yourself, but lodash already has the [`toPath`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toPath) function for that. It returns an array with each part of what we try to get.

Now that we know how to get to the key we want to delete, we could write some code that tests if each part exists and if each part is an object or an array. But, since we are now using lodash, we could make our lives easier by using [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) and [`_.isObjectLike`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isObjectLike):

```
import { toPath, get, isObjectLike } from 'lodash-es';

function deletePath(source, pathStr) {
    const path = toPath(pathStr);

    const selector = path.slice(0, -1);
    const key = path[path.length - 1];

    let deletableSource = source;

    if (selector.length && isObjectLike(source)) {
      deletableSource = get(source, selector);
    }

    if (isObjectLike(deletableSource)) {
      // We can delete something from this!
      this.$delete(deletableSource, key);
    }
}
```

Now that we have that, we can do something like assigning it to the `Vue` prototype, or exporting it as a helper function somewhere. I will rewriting your `addOption` as a reader's exercise.

[image: Edit How to delete entries from Vuex store using dynamic path as payload for a mutation?]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sumurai8, I figured out that it is possible to pass a parameter not as a string but actually **a reference to the store** like this. So ***no need to pass the sting*** with the path to the object in the state .

```
<button @click="deleteOption($store.state.xmlValues.Offers[mainData.curOfferKey].data.Pars)">delete</button>
```

The lodash **get** and **toPath** function was also very useful!